# Issues with wordpress Max upload size

Tags: php

So I have wordpress plugin that sets my max upload file size and currently it is set to 536mb. (which should be more then enough) But still when I try to upload 3,3 mb .xml file I get an error:

> The uploaded file exceeds the `upload_max_filesize` directive in `php.ini`.

[When trying to Upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zlgbd.png)

Comment: Do you have access to the php.ini file on your hosting server?

Comment: Hi, Yes I do have access.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  I tried editing the wp-config.php file and added:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '32M');
```

edited the .htaccess and added:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 32M
php_value post_max_size 32M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

none of the above seemed to work for me. I also tried locating the php.ini file on my directory but couldn't find it.

I created my php.ini file and added:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 32M
```

still nothing changed.

***MY SOLUTION***

I went back to my cPanel home page and located the **MultiPHP INI Editor**  under the **SOFTWARE** tab, selected my *domain name* from the dropdown menu and opened its PHP configuration, scrolled down to the bottom and located the **upload_max_filesize** directive and changed it from **2MB** to the size i want.

That solved my problem. Hope it works for you as well

Answer (score 1):

Open the php.ini file on your hosting server (Typically located somewhere like:
/usr/bin/php5/bin/php.ini in Linux) and adjust the following lines:

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.

```
upload_max_filesize = 536M
```

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize

```
post_max_size = 536M
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My php.ini file right now:
memory_limit = 536Mupload_max_filesize = 536Mpost_max_size = 536Mfile_uploads = Onmax_execution_time = 300.
Looks good?

Comment: Im on host not Local. So Can not really restart it.